# jQuery clone of JSON object returns undefined

Tags: jquery, json, clone

According to the docs, [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is a solution to execute both a deep and shallow copy of a JSON object.  However, when I use this, I get an undefined object error.

My ajax request function and handler:

```
var tourData;

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=stops",
  dataType: "json", 
  success: (function(data){
    if (data == 'false')
      console.log("Can't load initial panorama");
    else 
      processOptions(data);

  })
});

function processOptions(data){
  tourData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
  console.log(data.length);
  console.log(tourData.length);

}
```

In Firebug, `data.length` returns 6, which is what I expected.  However, `tourData` returns undefined.  This occurs with and without `true` as a parameter for a deep copy

I'm going to need the data from this request avaliable to several functions later on, and those functions will be out of scope.  As such, I'd like to have a clone of the response avaliable.

The contents of `data` are

```
[
  {"fileName":"..\/panos\/photos\/1-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","name":"Start","lat":"43.682211","lon":"-70.450705","heading":"250","width":"1808","height":"653"},
  {"fileName":"..\/panos\/photos\/2-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","name":"Second","lat":"43.6822","lon":"-70.450769","heading":"250","width":"1600","height":"578"},
  {"fileName":"..\/panos\/photos\/2-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","name":"Second","lat":"43.6822","lon":"-70.450769","heading":"250","width":"1600","height":"578"},
  {"fileName":"..\/panos\/photos\/3-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","name":"Third Stop","lat":"43.682219","lon":"-70.450828","heading":"250","width":"1821","height":"627"},
  {"fileName":"..\/panos\/photos\/4-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","name":"Fourth Stop","lat":"43.68218","lon":"-70.450887","heading":"250","width":"1600","height":"800"},
  {"fileName":"..\/panos\/photos\/5-prefix_blended_fused.jpg","name":"Last Stop","lat":"43.682165","lon":"-70.450933","heading":"250","width":"1808","height":"673"}
]
```

Comment: It seems like `data` is an array.  `console.log(data)`, let's see what's in there.

Comment: Yep, data is an array, not an object.  What so you want `$.extend` to do here?  What is the output you desire?

Comment: data is a JSON object.  I want to make a copy of it so it is avaliable outside of the ajax request and handler scope.

Comment: `tourData = data;`?  `data` is an array (of objects), not an object.

Comment: Don't you have to use a deep copy function for that?

Comment: `data` is a JSON object :O There's nothing like a JSON object :)

Comment: @Jason: No, that's only if you're merging 2 objects.  It tells it to merge arrays/objects recursively, instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You say `data.length` is 6.  This makes me think that `data` is an array, not an object.</strike>

`data` is not an object, it's an array.

`$.extend` will work with arrays, but the `length` property will no longer exist, as it converts it to an object.

```
var data = [{a:12}, {a:13}, {a:14}];
console.log(data.length); // 3
data = $.extend(true, {}, data);
console.log(data); // {0:{a:12}, 1:{a:13}, 2:{a:14}}
console.log(data.length); // undefined
```

Comment: This was the solution.  Thanks!